# How can one use Boost with Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, mingw

I'm having a lot of trouble installing Boost for use with Eclipse C++ (compiler MinGW).

I first tried downloading the zip at `https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.61.0/`. After it downloaded, I brought it to my second drive, extracted the files there, cd there, and then ran `./bootstrap.bat gcc`, which appeared to run successfully.

Then, I ran `b2 install --prefix="D:\boostfiles" toolset=gcc` and it took about 30 minutes to create a lot of files starting with `bin.v2` and ending with `rst`.

However, `#include <boost/asio.hpp>` still gives an error. Is there somewhere the files are supposed to be?

For reference, my file structure includes the original `boost_1_61_0` extracted folder, a folder that boost was installed to called `boostfiles`, and a folder called `PFiles` that includes both `eclipse` and `MinGW`.

Comment: Have you added boost to the INCLUDE path and the stage dir to the LIB path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing what I originally posted to install and configure Boost, follow these simple steps:

Go to Project Settings -> C/C++ Build -> Settings:

C++ Compiler -> Includes -> Include paths -> Add...

Add "(directory)\include\boost_x_xx"

C++ Linker -> Libraries -> Library search path -> Add...

Add "(target_directory)\lib"

C++ Linker -> Libraries -> Libraries -> Add...

Add (name of library without beginning "lib" or ending ".a")

For example: `libboost_system-mgw49-mt-1_61.a` becomes `boost_system-mgw49-mt-1_61`.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding Boost to the Include and Library search paths.

Go to **Project Settings** -> **C/C++ Build** -> **Settings**:

- **C++ Compiler** -> Includes -> Include paths -> Add...

  - Add "<target_dir>\include\boost_x_xx"
- **C++ Linker** -> Libraries -> Library search path -> Add...

  - Add "<target_dir>\lib"

Comment: I have `boostfiles/lib` but no stage anywhere I look, directions?

Comment: Yes, just use the files from the target dir (boostfiles/lib)

Comment: I have Includes set to D:\boost_1_61_0 and Libraries set to D:\boostfiles\lib;                                                                                                 Now I get an error: d:/pfiles/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lD:\boostfiles\lib

Comment: Both paths must be in double-quotes

Comment: Includes was already in " ", just fixed Libraries to be in " ". However, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and here is how it is solved.

The path to Boost libraries is ("**C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_62_0**")

Go to Project Settings -> C/C++ Build -> Settings:

**C++ Compiler** -> Includes -> **Include paths** -> Add...

Add "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_62_0"

**C++ Linker** -> Libraries -> **Library search path** -> Add...

Add "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_62_0\libs"